# Rails, gem choice for authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, authorization

I am building an app which aims to help shops organise their staff. There are many shops and each shop has many roles for the staff. The only constant position is the manager's one. I would like to enable him/her to create his/her own roles. For example, in shop A, the delivery guy may update order_status, but in shop B, he may not.
As you can see, I would like the roles to be custom and to be constrained in the specific shop.
I am considering three gems for the authorization - cancancan, rolify and pundit(but I am open to suggestions). Rolify is not that famous one but it has the convinient option to say

```
user.has_role?(:manager, Shop.find(4))
```

Which gem do you think is the best choice? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I found the following link extremely helpful. [Click](https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/10/23/dynamic-roles-and-permissions-using-cancan/)

Comment: A popular gem for "roles" is [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pundit manage permission through policies and I think that is the best.

You can crete an app/policies/application_policy.rb that manage actions like index/show/create....

```
  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end
```

And after that generate policies like

```
class MyClassPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
end
```

Check pundit documentation.

About roles you can use: role model gem (https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) that manage roles too easy. Check the example and ask if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The response to your question would be based on the opinions of the answerer. In my opinion, I'd prefer CanCanCan, largely because I've used it for a while, understanding the setup may be a bit of problem at first, but once gotten over that, it's all a smooth sail. It's simple logic also allows me to use enums within my application and get to productivity in no time. Others would argue Pundit, which is also simple to setup and easy to integrate and ease of working with other libraries, such as rolify and devise etc. There may not be a right or wrong answer in this case, but I guess it would ultimately be determined by your specific use case and the amount of time you have for setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you say for authorization than [Pundit Gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)  is best as per your requirement.

But as per my knowledge not only pundit or any gem do all things for you. You need to give dynamic permission to all user as per shop. So you need to manage with your database setup also.

You need three table like.

> User
>   Role
>   Permission

and set relationship as below

```
user has_one role
role has_many permissions
user has_many permissions through role
```

Above scenario is just an example the core logic may vary depend on your requirements.

Hope this will help you.